# Draw polygon wire in Maya using OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, maya

I'm looking for fast way of drawing polygon wireframe in Maya using openGL. I have a working solution, however it's very slow for complex scenes.

I also have a fast solution using MGeometry and MGeometryPrimitive, however it gives me triangles and I can't see a way to get polygon definition.

I am only interested in points and polygon definition, I don't care about normals, UVs and such.

Here's my working slow solution:

```
MPointArray points;
for (MItMeshPolygon oPolyIter(object); !oPolyIter.isDone(); oPolyIter.next())
{
    gGLFT->glBegin(MGL_LINE_LOOP);
    oPolyIter.getPoints(points);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < points.length(); i++)
        gGLFT->glVertex3d(points[i].x, points[i].y, points[i].z);
    gGLFT->glEnd();
}
```

Any ideas or pointers?

Comment: Change glDrawMode to Wire?

Comment: Thanks for comment, but it's sort of implied. I just haven't showed this part of code.

Comment: Ahh okay. Sorry, I kind of skimmed over it. I've seen people try to do this with GL_LINES. Anyways, drawing it in wireframe shouldn't be any slower than drawing in polygons.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I came up with this solution, which runs considerably faster.

```
gGLFT->glPolygonMode(MGL_FRONT_AND_BACK, MGL_LINE);
MIntArray verts;
UintArray vertIds;
for (int i = 0 ; i < mesh.numPolygons(); i++)
{
    mesh.getPolygonVertices(i, verts);
    vertIds.convert(verts);
    gGLFT->glDrawElements(GL_POLYGON, verts.length(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, vertIds.data() );
}
```